# selecting an element in drop down list is failing in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium to automate the web application. It consist select option from a menu i just need to hover mouse on that so that the options will appear and i can select one of them but following code for select the option thrown an exception as below,

i used moseOver for the menu

```
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

and for option

```
element.click();
```

Exception:-

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"ARINC Loader Settings"}
Command duration or timeout: 1.57 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_13'
Session ID: 08f4ccbc-7b13-4c2a-a2db-387dcf0022a7
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=24.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:356)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
    at com.honeywell.corept.tests.MainTest.webTest(MainTest.java:114)
    at com.honeywell.corept.tests.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:264)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"ARINC Loader Settings"}
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_13'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Comment: can you paste your html code?

Comment: <html><head><body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 1024px;">
<style><script type="text/javascript">
<img src="/corept/resources/images/header.png"><div class="menu" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
<script><div style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
<style><div style="padding: 5px;">
<div class="header">System Profile</div><div class="system-profile">
<div><div><div></div>
<div style="margin-top: 50px; width: 550px;"></div><script></div>
<div style="background-color: white; bottom: 0px; color: gray; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px; left: 5px; position: fixed; padding-bottom: 5px;">
</body></h

Comment: you can actually edit ur question to paste ur code...it'l improve readability..

Comment: it is not able to find this link "ARINC Loader Settings"...

Comment: you should try and find out why this exception is thrown...**Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"ARINC Loader Settings"}
**

Comment: this exception has nothing to do with "mouse over and click"..

Comment: actaully my problem is admin is the name of that menu and ARINC loader one of the option in the drop down of admin i have to go to admin and select that option even if i give click for admin i cant see the options displayed while testing.......

Comment: so the problem is "click on menu didn't work"?..can u please edit ur html code,its not clear enough..

Answer (score 2):

instead you need to chain all of the actions that you want to achieve in one go. So move to the element that reveals the others, then during the same chain, move to the now revealed element and click on it.

use this,

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver)
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("element xpath"));
action.moveToElement(we).moveToElement(webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("element xpath")).click().build().perform();
```

hope this help you.